# How to setup custom site routes created by user in plugin settings

Tags: plugin-development, routes, routing

In my plugin settings I am allowing the user to specify url formats for each locale along with desired template path, much like sections.  How do I then register those custom url formats as site routes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`registerSiteRoutes()`](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#registerSiteRoutes) hook in your plugin's primary class.

Assuming your custom URL formats are stored in an array in a plugin setting called `customRoutes` (use `AttributeType::Mixed` for arrays), and that the array consists of key/value paired routes and template paths:

```
public function registerSiteRoutes()
{
    return $this->getSettings()['customRoutes'] ?: array();
}
```

Here's how the `customRoutes` array should look:

```
array(
    'some-custom-route' => '_some-custom-template',
    'another-custom-route' => '_another-custom-template',
),
```

Comment: If the route has brackets for tokens will Craft parse that or does it need to be converted somehow?

Comment: Unlike URL formats for entries and categories, routes declared with `registerSiteRoutes()` use [sub patterns](https://craftcms.com/docs/routing#accessing-subpatterns-in-your-templates) for parameters and won't parse Twig or URL format tokens (i.e. `{slug}`). What kind of variables do you need in your routes?

Comment: So entries and categories because they are elements use the element's `routeRequestForMatchedElement` method?  I was trying to give admins ability to set any variable like section urlFormat provides for entires.

Comment: What's the context for those variables, though? E.g. `{slug}` in an Section's URL format is really just short for `{entry.slug}`, but unlike URL formats, a generic route doesn't have that kind of context. To give any further advice or suggestions, it'd be helpful to learn more about your actual use case – what kind of routes are your admins going to add, and what kind of variables are you wanting to expose to those routes?

Comment: Admins will probably use slug, date('y-m-d') & id as most common types of variables.

Comment: I think you have two options – either write some custom logic in `registerSiteRoutes` to rewrite whatever "bracket variables" the user has added to valid sub patterns, i.e. `{slug}` becomes `(?P<slug>[-\w]+)` (don't see how you can avoid having every sub pattern accept any character, as opposed to having different kinds of sub patterns as per [the official docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/routing#accessing-subpatterns-in-your-templates)). The other option is to have a set of pre-defined variables (i.e. _tokens_), that are replace with different kinds of sub patterns.

Comment: The latter approach – pre-defined tokens representing various sub patterns – is how the routing UI inside the Craft CP works, so you might check out how P&T built it and try to reuse or recreate some of that functionality.